# ROS is missing a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, ros

Every time I try to install ROS to my system and run the command `sudo apt update`, a package is not found. I tried most of the solutions offered here but the problem still shows up.

The error message is:

> The repository "http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release'
> does not have a Release file.

[image]

Comment: If the repository doesn't exist, it's hard to think of a solution you could try that would fix the problem.

Comment: A quick look using the link you provided shows **no support for jammy** or 22.04, did you look?